# Should an application check for UUID v4 duplicated?

Tags: python, uuid

I work in my app with a database.
This database stores data with a randomly generated ID of the type UUID v4.
Now I'm wondering, how common is it for a big (let's be optimistic :D ) app with many users to have a duplicate ID? The ID is the primary key in the SQL database so it could only crash one API call.
Is it a clean practice to check if the UUID exists (and thus catch a possible crash in the backend) or is it redundant as it's very unlikely to happen?

Especially considering:

- random in python is not that random
- there are 2¹²² combinations

## EDIT:

Based on the comments it seems unnecessary to check for duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, what does `random` have to do with anything?

Comment: Do you consider 1 in 2^122 "very unlikely"?

Comment: If the database is enforcing uniqueness, then duplicates aren't a data integrity issue. I would just wait for collisions to actually be a problem before implementing retry logic. Bad retry logic can cause problems of its own.

Comment: Use a UUID and when you get a collision in a couple billion of years time, you can make a new question "How to fix a UUID collision"

Comment: In my personal view, not shared by others, this is why the older UUID formats were better.  Unless someone is on my machine and generates 4 billion UUIDs in a single second, they are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I check in some cases, but that is just to ensure I haven't made some programmatic error, it's a pretty simple unit test.

Comment: If you get a collision, that probably means a spaceship running on an Infinite Improbability Drive just stopped nearby for a pickup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem in practice due to the very low probability of collisions.

See the Wikipedia article on [UUID4 collision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions)

> For example, the number of random version-4 UUIDs which need to be
> generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision
> is 2.71 quintillion
>
> This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for
> about 85 years. A file containing this many UUIDs, at 16 bytes per
> UUID, would be about 45 exabytes.

*NB. UUID1 and UUID2 have a time component which make it impossible to have collisions if the UUIDs are generated at a reasonable enough frequency.*